# How to get element inside iframe using chrome console?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm using a website that doesn't have playback speed for videos. I want to increase the speed. But the problem is the video is inside an iframe. Here's my current code that I paste in the chrome console:

```
// this works
iframe = document.querySelector('iframe') 
// this does not work even though there is a video element inside the frame, it can't find it.
iframe.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1.2
```

If I manually click inside the iframe, and run `document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1.2`, it works, but it is troublesome to click inside the frame to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `contentDocument` property to access the document in the iframe:

```
iframe = document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument
iframe.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1.2
```

Note that this will only work if the iframe is in the same domain as the top-level document.